# Linq, where entity property contains another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list:

List of strings:

```
var keywords = _db.KeyWords.Select(k => k.Word);
```

and list of objects:

```
var articles = _db.Articles;
```

What I want to achieve is to filter articles where article properties contains keywords, for example:

```
var model = articles.Where(a => a.Title.Contains(keywords) || a.Description.Contains(keywords));
```

Is  possible in one query without foreach loop?

One solution is :

```
 List<Article> model = new List<Article>();
 foreach (var keyword in keywords)
 {
     model.AddRange(articles.Where(a => a.Title.Contains(keyword) || a.Description.Contains(keyword)));
 }
```

But i have 100 keywords, and it is heavy process using foreach loop.

Comment: Ok what is wrong with this query? It is "one query without foreach loop".

Comment: It is error, keywords is list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In words, you need to take only those items which have any word from `keywords`. So, in LINQ it can be done with something like:

```
var model = articles
    .Where(a => keywords.Any(k => a.Title.Contains(k) || a.Description.Contains(k)))
    .ToList();
```

If title or description does not contain any word from `keywords`, then it will not be added in the resulted list.

Note that it will not improve time complexity compared with `foreach`, but it may improve readbility.
In general, any algorithm iterating through all the keywords and articles, is going to take approximately **`Number of articles * Number of keywords * Average length of article`** operations, which grows pretty fast when variables grow. Keep it in mind.

Comment: LOL, I was only 10 minutes late, +1 for using  a (articles) & k (keywords), baffles me when people use random letters

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your foreach-style example is wrong. If you have an article containing `"foo bar"` and keywords `"foo"` and `"bar"`, the article will be included twice.

You want to loop through articles first, then through keywords. Here's this without any linq at all:

```
List<Article> model = new List<Article>();
foreach (var article in articles)
{
    foreach (var keyword in keywords)
    {
        if (article.Title.Contains(keyword) || article.Description.Contains(keyword))
        {
            model.Add(article);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty straightforward to translate this into a linq query:

```
var model = articles.Where(
                a => keywords.Any(
                     k => a.Title.Contains(k) || a.Description.Contains(k))).ToList();
```

Comment: I have almost 100 000 articles, and it increases permanently. Use foreach loop would ruin my application

Comment: When it comes to performance, linq is not your best friend. That being said, you can't expect to be able to return any matching article without going through them all. It is definitely possible to search for keywords more efficiently though, but that's a whole different topic.

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili Iterating through all the keywords and aritcles is going to have a pretty big time copmlexity: **`N of articles * N of keywords * Average length of article`** time. Consider this when using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method.

For your solution:

```
var model = articles
           .Where(a => !keywords.Any(k => a.Title.Contains(k) || a.Description.Contains(k)))
           .ToList();
```

Here is a basic example to understand the method:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pet { get; set; }
}

List<string> animals = new List<string>();
animals.Add("donkey");
animals.Add("horse");

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = "Marco",
    Pet = "horse"
});
people.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = "John",
    Pet = "donkey"
});
people.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = "Penny",
    Pet = "dog"
});

//result will only include people who have pets that are in the animal list.
var res = people.Where(p => animals.Any(a => p.Pet.Contains(a)));

foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", item.Name, item.Pet);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```